# layout with top bar, bottom bar & remaining space content view

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm getting crazy with the android views. I want a layout with a bar on top (A) and one bar one the bottom (C) of my app with `height="wrap_content"`. The full remaining space in the middle (B) should be the content area with another Layout or `TextView` or whatever. But i can't get this to work. I tried a lot with the layouts, but when i do `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to B, C disappears. Any ideas? Thanks in advance[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use android:layout_weight property to achieve that, but your parent container has to be a **LinearLayout**, in my example I'm using just LinearLayout as children of the parent view but you can use another type of View:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/container"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/layout_a"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/layout_b"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="1">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/layout_c"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

If you're curious and wanna know how it works... here is the [explanation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html), good luck :)

Comment: using weight solves this issue. simple answer and it works. thx to all answers

Comment: Works fine, after changed in main linear layout android:layout_height="wrap_content" to android:layout_height="match_parent"

Answer (score 0):

Put the contents into a `RelativeLayout` with `alignParentTop` and `alignParentBottom` attributes for content **A** and **C** and also `below` and `above` related attribute to content **B**, as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <!-- create content A and C before -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/A"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" > </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/C"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" > </LinearLayout>
    <!-- create content B regarding the previous ids -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/B"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/A"
        android:layout_above="@id/C"
        android:orientation="vertical" > </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can try to change the content **B**'s height with `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent` if this doesn't work. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yep, this'll work, just mocked up a view with the same spec and it worked out fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use weight:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/A"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp">
        <!-- Your view here or replace FrameLayout -->
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/B"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <!-- Your view here or replace FrameLayout -->
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/C"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp">
        <!-- Your view here or replace FrameLayout -->
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Setting height to 0 is good for performance reasons, since weight will change it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/top_bar"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"/>
 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/middle_area"
    android:layout_weight="14"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"/>
  <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"/>
```

android_layout_weight in combination with LinearLayout can do the trick for you. Try the above code and adjust the android_layout_weight according to your need.
In my example the top bar will take 1/16 th of the screen the bottom bar would take 1/16th of the screen and the middle_area would take 14/16 th of the screen. You can change the numbers to your custom needs.