# Adding a Layout to the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following XML layout.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:textSize="50px"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/itemNumber"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/itemNumber"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <Button 
            android:text="Submit" 
            android:id="@+id/Button"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/EditText" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </EditText>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What i need to do is make the Edit Text & the Button to appear in the bottom of the screen. I'm using the 3 Text Views to appear as a List View. So i can choose one from the list and enter it into the Edit Text to submit the value.

But I cannot make 'em appear in the bottom. How can i do this?

Comment: Have you closed the second RelativeLayout?

Comment: This might help!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779688/put-buttons-at-bottom-of-screen-with-linearlayout

Comment: @RafaelCardoso I'm sorry, yes i have. Missed it while copy/pasting

Comment: here's a good simple solution using a 3-part LinearLayout: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23746100/2162226

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
```

With

```
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

// Take a look at this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="textView 1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="textView 2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="textView 3" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="submit" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It worked, Thank you... But I need to have those 3 Text Views at the Top. Now Those 3 has stretched up to the bottom. Any suggestions?

Comment: How you want to align your textviews vertically or horizontally.

Comment: Take a Header view @k9yosh....check my answer and ..you have to just put a header layout ..nd in scrollview container put this android:layout_below="@id/header" >

Comment: @k9yosh, I have updated my answer if you don't mind you can try this layout it looks exactly what you want(If i am not wrong). You just need to modify according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

just add thie line of code :

```
android:gravity="bottom"
```

Edit : more easy to change the second layout to : LinearLayout